# Как сделать, чтобы слайды листались один за другим в обе стороны?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пытаюсь в нём сделать, чтобы при каждом скролле мышкой вверх или вниз менялись классы, к которым привязаны слайдеры. Они должны меняться по одному слайду за скролл, а у меня, как я не старался, скачут, как только могут.

```
var y = 1;

var x = 2;

$(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {

    var cur = $('.pt-page-' + y);
    var next = $('.pt-page-' + x);

    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    //up

        if (y > 1) {
            $(cur).removeClass('pt-page-moveFromBottom');
            $(cur).addClass('blurA');
            $(next).addClass('pt-page-moveFromTop pt-page-ontop');
            $(next).removeClass('blurA');
            x--;
            y--;

        }

        else
        {
            alert('nothing top');
        }
    }
    else {
    //down
            if (y < 4){
                $(cur).addClass('blurA');
                $(cur).removeClass('pt-page-moveFromTop pt-page-ontop');

                $(next).removeClass('blurA');
                $(next).addClass('pt-page-moveFromBottom pt-page-current');
                x++;
                y++;
            }
        else
            {
                alert("nothing-bot");
            }
        }

});


$(document).ready();
```

Comment: Переформулируйте, пж-та, заголовок вопроса так, чтобы он содержал краткую суть вашей задачи.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что неинформативный заголовок, лишающий вопрос пользы для ru-SO.

Comment: Переформулировал заголовок, надеюсь теперь он отвечает Вашим стандартам.

Comment: Да, теперь вполне пойдёт)

Comment: `cur` уже jQuery объект, нет необходимости в `$(cur)`. Кроме того вы подписываетесь на два события _mousewheel DOMMouseScroll_ скорее всего они оба и происходят

Comment: можете добавить пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?